# ORA-01481: invalid number format model (convert number to char)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, to-char

I'm confused as to why I'm getting this error. I use a function that stores a NUMBER variable and returns a NUMBER (e.g. 123456).

I want to convert this to a format of my choosing, so I would use to_char:

```
 select to_char(total_count_prods('apple'),'1234-56') from dual;
```

And I keep getting that error. What's the issue? If I run

```
select total_count_prods('apple') from dual;
```

Then I get the following output:

```
 123456
```

How can I convert that to:

```
 1234-56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(total_apples, 1, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(total_apples, 5)
FROM   (
  SELECT total_count_prods('apple') AS total_apples
  FROM   DUAL
);
```

Or `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         total_count_prods('apple'),
         '(\d{2})$',
         '-\1'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or, divide by 100 and use `TO_CHAR` and set the decimal separator to `-`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         total_count_prods('apple')/100,
         'FM9999D99',
         'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=-,'
       )
FROM   dual;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7_BTq_WB)

Comment: Awesome, I like the expression one since it's minimalistic! What if I want to add another hyphen in between (ex. 12-34-56) using expressions?

Comment: @BFF You can use `'(\d{2})(\d{2})$', '-\1-\2'`

Answer (score 0):

Your function `total_count_prods()` is returning a number, exactly as you would expect. The problem is that `'1234-56'` is not a valid format model for converting a number to a string - exactly as the error says.